# TronWeb via a proxy server

Tags: tron, tronweb

I'm using TronWeb with to broadcast transactions:

```
const tronWeb = new TronWeb({
      fullHost: "https://api.trongrid.io",
      headers: { "TRON-PRO-API-KEY": myTronApiKey },
      privateKey: walletKey
    })
```

I would like to change it now so that it does through a proxy server and not directly to "https://api.trongrid.io".
How can I do this?